# Are there any primitive examples besides 56,65 where the sum of a number's cube and its digital reverse's cubes is square?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion, perfect-powers

I saw a question a while back which asked (paraphrased): how many examples exist of the form $a^n + b^n = c^2$ where $b$ is $a$'s digits in reverse, $n \geq 2$, and $a,b,c$ are coprime.

For $n = 2$, the proof is not too hard that there are zero solutions (via mod 3).

For $n \geq 4$, the reverse part isn't even needed, there are no solutions (http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa86/aa8631.pdf contains a proof).

For $n = 3$, $56^3 + 65^3$ is a square. My question is whether there exists more cases. Trying mod 9 gives some restrictions, but I couldn't narrow it that significantly. Coding a quick test shows there are no other "small solutions" (Up to a = 10 million). Code viewable here: https://codeinterview.io/YRGDWJVCAH

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! That's nicely researched for a first question, keep it up! Maybe you could provide the code that you used for the cubic case and try to find the original question to round this post out.

Comment: @TheOutrageousZ Thanks, I added a code link. The original question I couldn't find, but there was nothing else on it. No discussion of any sort.

Comment: Are you sure about the proof for $n=2$? It seems that $a$ could be a multiple of $9$ without immediate contradiction, for example.

Comment: @abnew123 Some food for thought: It might also be fruitful to look at $x^3+x_r^3 = y^2 \mod 11$, since the powers of ten just alternate signs here. I haven't done the case reduction, but maybe it can be used in conjunction with your experiments $\mod 9$. Also (but I'm not sure about that) maybe the sum of two cubes $\mod$ some number don't cover all residue classes, so with the limited selection of squares we can _maybe_ try to infer something?

Comment: @abnew123 After brushing up on my Mathematica knowledge, I coded up a function that can (probably not efficiently) figure out the residue classes of a sum of powers and of a single power. Have made a mistake in my calculation, will correct it shortly and post if anything meaningful pops out.

Comment: @abnew123 I can post my code if you want to look into it. The best candidate (in terms of having less than $\frac{n}{4}$ possible residue classes $\mod n$) is $n = 28$. Calculating the residues for both sides $\mod 28$, one arrives at that $x$ is a solution iff $x \equiv \{0,1,8,9,16,21\} \mod 28$. Technically, it is "stronger" than the result $\mod 9$, but that doesn't guarantee that it's going to be useful in any way.

Comment: To clarify, in the comment above I calculated solutions to $x^3+y^3 \equiv z^2 \mod n$, apologies for that. But this is of course a generalization of your problem, so it shouldn't be too hard to check residues of the reversed number.

Comment: @GregMartin if a is a multiple of 9, then b is also a multiple of 9 (since they have the same digit sum), so a and b are not coprime.

Comment: oohhhh I totally missed the coprimality assumption!